# SpreadSheetGear 2012 copy range with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, spreadsheetgear

I have a range with Conditional Formatting in an existing Excel file. I'm trying to use SpreadSheetGear 2012 to copy that range to a new sheet, then I found the conditional formatting was missing:

`IRange someRange = mySheet.Range["EXISTINGRANGE"];
someRange["A1:AX45"].Copy(newWorksheet.Cells["A3"]);`

Is there any way to copy range with conditional formatting using SpreadSheetGear?

Answer (score 1):

I contact with SpreadSheetGear Technical Support and they pointed out the product limitations about this feature:

> You might first check whether your Conditional Formatting is even present in the source range, as you might find it is not there.  If so, this can likely be explained by the fact that SpreadsheetGear 2012 has limited support for CF features available up through Excel 2003.  If your CF’s use any features that were added in Excel 2007+ (specifying more than 3 rules as well as other common features like using “advanced” or overlapping rules, rule ordering, 24-bit colors, color scales, data bars, icon sets and other graphical features, etc.), then you will find that these particular CF’s will be dropped upon opening your workbook in SpreadsheetGear.

They suggested to use the latest version.

Comment: SpreadsheetGear 2017 and later has vastly enhanced its support for conditional formatting--supporting all the features available in current versions of Excel (Excel 2019 at the moment). If you are having trouble with Conditional Formatting and using an older version such as SpreadsheetGear 2012 / V7 or earlier, try upgrading to see if the issue goes away.